# Parse Push JSON data issue on Android

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, push-notification

I am pretty new to Android and I really hope this will be easy to solve for you guys!

I would like to let users send push to other users after pressing a button on my app.
It did correctly configure ParsePush on my button click listener because this works fine:

```
            // Create our Installation query
            ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
            pushQuery.whereEqualTo("installationId", installationId); //Send to targeted user

            // Send push notification to query
            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query

            push.setMessage("HEY YOU");
            push.sendInBackground();
```

But I would like to add a URI in my push, so I did:

```
                // Create our Installation query
            ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
            pushQuery.whereEqualTo("installationId", installationId);

            // Send push notification to query
            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query

            String string = "{\"title\" : \"my title\",\"alert\" : \"my alert text\",\"uri\" : \"myapp://host/path\"}";

            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(string);
                push.setData(data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }

            push.sendInBackground();
```

In my Android Manifest I have the targeted Activity:

```
        <activity android:name=".Accept_Action">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="host" android:path="/path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But for some reason this is not working. The push never lands on my targeted device.
Can you help me make this work? 
Thanks

Comment: :) yes I do know, thanks for your concern. But I started on Parse, and my MVP is almost finished so I wanted to unlock this last part.
Plus, it is actually boost my overall knowledge of Java and Android dev

Comment: Do you see any error in logs ? Do you see the push sent in the parse interface?

Comment: No errors on my logs, no notification in parse Inteface :/ @meynety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

Sadly, for security reason, you cannot use the "uri" option of parse push from a client.

Sources :

- This blog post http://blog.parse.com/learn/android-push-gets-major-refresh/ :

  > As a security precaution, the uri option may not be used when a push is sent from a client.
- And from the errors section in parse docs https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#errors-push-related-errors :

  > ClientPushWithURI 115 Client-initiated push cannot use the "uri"
  >   option.

**Suggestions for a solution**

I see two possible solutions for this problem :

- Send the push from a cloud code function (https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions) that you call from your Android clients.
- Use a name other than `uri` and implement your own logic to handle it (overwrite `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`, example : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/)

**For learning purpose**

You could have seen this error simply by implementing the callback of the sendInBackground() action, to see the actual result of the action, like this :

```
push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } else {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "Push sent.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Therefore, `e.printStackTrace();` would have print you the above error 115 :

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Client-initiated push cannot use the "uri" option
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. Let me test it and get back to you!

Comment: Hey @meynety, sorry for taking so long to get back to you. 
I am now working on a cloud code function as suggested!
Thanks for your help!